# LOAD DATA INFILE blocks on concurrent use against MyISAM tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm having trouble loading data into MyISAM table(s) concurrently using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. The loading operation works fine in isolation. Trying to do `LOAD DATA INFILE` operations concurrently, blocks – a system lock, in MySQL profiling information – until the previous is finished. This happens independent of loading into the same/different table, or even a different database. InnoDB does not have the same problems, however, MyISAM seems better suited for a pure logging-table.

Can concurrent `LOAD DATA INFILE` operations be done with MyISAM engine on MySQL? Am I missing some crucial settings (DISABLE KEYS is automatic against an empty database)? Tested on MySQL 5.1.63 and 5.5.14.

I expected loading using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to different tables concurrently to be performant, however, performance is instead completely destroyed.

---

To replicate my scenario:

#### SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE TABLE `log_isam` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE log_isam ADD INDEX num(num);

CREATE TABLE `log_isam2` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE log_isam2 ADD INDEX num(num);
```

#### LOAD DATA log.txt file contents

https://gist.github.com/4245602

#### Shell script

```sh
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=PASS
time mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -e \
    "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/log.txt' \
     INTO TABLE log_isam FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" test & \
time mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -e \
    "LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/log.txt' \
     INTO TABLE log_isam2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent `LOAD DATA INFILE` on MyISAM tables are limited by mutex congestion due a global Key Cache. To alleviate lock congestion, MyISAM tables can be set to have their own Key Cache.

```
SET GLOBAL isam_cache.key_buffer_size=8*1024;
SET GLOBAL isam_cache_two.key_buffer_size=8*1024;
CACHE INDEX log_isam IN isam_cache;
CACHE INDEX log_isam2 IN isam_cache_two;
```

Comment: Since my answer did not help, I can remove it. +1 for you !!!